# Programmatically control height of a secondary view into a parse tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this `PFQueryTableViewController` and I added a `view` on top of the tableView to add comments.

I am trying to change the height of this view when the user click in one of these 3 methods of upload.

The image 2 shows the view expanded (did that programatically), but it haven't push the tableView cells downwards. They are now overlapping.

Any idea about how to push this tableview downwards?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

**Parse arrangement**

[image]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 2):

try it after click

```
tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 800.0 //new table cell size
tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableview.reloadData()
```

or

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 800; //tableviewcell height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard file shows that you are not using any constraints, so i assume that you are doing everything in programatically,

after setting the view's height, change the tableview y position and height

```
tableview.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(tableView.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame), CGRectGetWidth(tableview.frame), screenHeight- view height);
```

Height of the table should be set according to your requirement.

Comment: Parse do not allow you to add constraints on the storyboard. I tried your suggestion but it has no effect on a tableview of type pfquerytableviewcontroller. I think I will have to work my self around placing this tableview inside a container view.